# How do query post data in WordPress with parameters that have been entered by a user?

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type, wpallimport

I need to create a WordPress page which will be used by customers to type in their email address and last 4 of their phone number to query the information stored in WordPress (customer id, points, etc.).

So far I have all of the customer information imported from a CSV file using WpAllImport with Advanced Custom Fields. So the information is there, I am just stuck on how to allow the user to query their info based on what they submitted.

Normally I would develop this using LAMP or MERN, but this must be done with WP. Has anybody done something like this that could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Are you trying to enable a non-logged-in user be able to view user information ? You said you imported users informations from a CSV, meaning that those users are not registered yet ? Be a bit more specific on the end result, Are you trying to merge two user database from different CMS ?

Comment: Yes they will not be logged in. I want them to be able to type in their email address and the last 4 of their phone number into the form and retrieve their customer information. 

I am not trying to merge two databases. The company I am working for will just update to CSV file every 24 hours in WordPress and WpAllImport will be configured to import. 

I hope that makes it more clear. I built something like this before with a LAMP stack, but the customer is insistent on using WP.

Answer (score 0):

We can initially check if the email exist through [`email_exists()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/email_exists/) and if so, we can get the user by it's email trough [`get_user_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/) which will enable us to get the user phone.

```
if ( isset( $_GET['email'] ) && email_exists( $_GET['email'] ) ) {

    $user = get_user_by( 'email', $_GET['email'] );

    //...

};
```

We then need to make sure the user knows the phone number. At that point, identity is considered proven, and we can dump the user object (`WP_User`). Keep in mind that, security associated with that kind of a method is really (really) low and is probably going against personal privacy data law in place in most countries (eg: EU countries).

```
if ( isset( $_GET['email'] ) && email_exists( $_GET['email'] ) ) {

    $user = get_user_by( 'email', $_GET['email'] );

    if ( isset( $_GET['phone'] ) && str_contains( $user->phone, $_GET['phone'] ) ) {

        var_dump( $user );

    };

};
```

Additionally best practice would be to implement some kind [security token validation (nonces)](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces).

> A nonce is a "number used once" to help protect URLs and forms from certain types of misuse, malicious or otherwise. WordPress nonces aren't numbers but are a hash made up of numbers and letters. Nor are they used only once, but have a limited "lifetime" after which they expire. During that time period, the same nonce will be generated for a given user in a given context. The nonce for that action will remain the same for that user until that nonce life cycle has completed.